# How to make sure a Jinja custom tag only outputs once?

Tags: python, jinja2

I have a custom tag in Jinja2 that I want to output something only the first time that it is called.  So say I have the following template:

```
1. {% only_once %}
2. {% only_once %}
3. {% only_once %}
```

I want the output to be:

```
1. "I only get printed once!"
2.
3.
```

I'm guessing the best way to do this is to set a flag in the context of the template to track whether I've already printed something or not.  Here's a code sample, but is this right?

```
class OnlyOnceExtension(Extension):
    tags = set(['only_once'])

    @contextfunction
    def parse(self, context, parser):
        if hasattr(context, 'my_flag') and context.my_flag:
            return Output("")
        else:
            return Output("I only get printed once!")
```

Is that correct?  I read some stuff about the context is immutable, so will this not work?  (see http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/documentation/api and search for immutable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion is to implement this in Python code:

```
class OnlyOnce(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.printed = False

    def __str__(self):
        if self.printed is False:
            self.printed = True
            return self.data
        return ''
```

Create an `OnlyOnce` instance in your Python code and pass it to the template, and then every time you want to use it, just use `{{ only_once }}`.

One thing I notice about a lot of people using Jinja is that they want to do things in a Django-ish way, that is, writing extensions. But Jinja's expressions/importing/whatever is powerful enough that you don't have to use extensions for everything.

And yes, using the `context.my_flag` thing is a bad idea. Only the template gets to modify the context. **EVER.**

Comment: i wish i could turn this Answer into a new Question on StackOverflow for noobs lol

Comment: i have to leave one more comment on this...Whoever DOES understand this answer, would have the skills to overcome the question in the first place. How does this help the community? Looks like this answer is a higher dimension of thought for a programmer. must we assume the four principles of object-oriented programming our fully understood by the reader? if we do not make this assumption, what principle are you using to optimize the original attempt?

Answer (score 13):

If you want to do it purely with Jinja you can just check the loop.index variable in that fashion,

```
{% for bar in bars %}
    {% if loop.index == 1 %}
        Print me once
    {% endif %}
    Print me every time
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: your solution makes more sense. I was facing a similar issue but now its resolved. Thanks to you mate.

Answer (score 1):

I would define a boolean and a macro and go from there. Instead of printing the variable, you print the result of the macro which uses an if statement and the boolean to decide if it should print. So, you get the following:

```
{{ set was_printed = false }}
{% macro print_once(to_print) %}
    {% if was_printed is sameas false %}
        {{ to_print }}
        {% set was_printed = true %}
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
1. {% print_once(only_once) %}
2. {% print_once(only_once) %}
3. {% print_once(only_once) %}
```

Comment: I tried to use this macro but its not valid code, `TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of print statement', got 'was_printed'
`

Comment: The first line must be `{% set was_printed = false %}`.

Answer (score 0):

Jinja doesn't always re-evaluate macros, so setting a macro variable won't prevent a value from being created twice. The accepted solution works, but it requires you to hard code your object at the flask view level. 
I solved this by creating a custom jinja filter that will only return the value once per request.

***The filter:***

```
from flask import g    

def onetime(val, atr):
    """
    this filter will return the given value only once per request

    :param val: the value to return 1 time
    :type val: str
    :param atr: the attribute to remember this value by
    :type atr: str
    :return: returns True for this attribute once per request
    :rtype: str
    """
    # has this attribute been set for this request?
    if getattr(g, atr, False):
        # the value has already been returned for this request
        return ""
    # set the flag
    setattr(g, atr, True)
    # return the value, this is the first call
    return val
```

***Add the filter to your flask app***

```
app.jinja_env.filters['onetime'] = onetime
```

***Create a jinja macro containing the text your only want to output once:***
macros.html

```
{% macro my_macro() %}
This text should only be created once
{% endmacro %}
```

***And to use it:***

```
{{ my_macro() | onetime('a_name') }}
{{ my_macro() | onetime('a_name') }}
{{ my_macro() | onetime('a_name') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers are actually pretty good in their own context, but I recently had to tackle this, and I had to deviate slightly, which led into what I think is a more "generic" solution.

Using "loop variables" is IMO the right/elegant way to do this, but this only works if you are using loops to begin with.

In my case, I have a recursive macro (I have complex nested structures I need to traverse), so rendering "foo" only the first time the macro actually renders something was not super straightforward.

I tried to accomplish this with a variation of the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3159330) suggested by [nearlymonolith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/369522/nearlymonolith), using [namespaces](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-globals.namespace), and even though it worked, the result was really ugly, as I had to duplicate the same block multiple times:

```
{% set ns = namespace(printed=false) %}
{% if ns.printed == false%}
   {% set ns.printed = true %}
{{ print foo }}
{% endif %}
```

What I ended up doing was something similar to what [user2682863](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2682863/user2682863) suggested in their [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59813456).

Define and instantiate a `Once` object where attributes will be stored for future reference; then, in the filter itself we check if the attribute has already been stored or not to decide whether it should be rendered.

```py
    class Once(object):
        pass

    once = Once()

    # This is a "weird" filter, in the sense that it actually checks current
    # state of the "once" global variable to determine whether it should
    # return the requested value or not. In order to distinguish calls to the
    # filter, we use the current "context" as a way to namespace the calls to
    # the filter, otherwise this could only be used "once" per run, regardless
    # of the number of files generated. We also hash the value in order to
    # simplify the call to the filter (no arguments needed).
    @jinja2.pass_context
    def only_once(ctx, val):
        ctx_hash = hash(ctx)
        val_hash = hash(val)
        namespaced_attr = f"{ctx_hash}_{val_hash}"
        if getattr(once, namespaced_attr, False):
            # The value has already been returned for this attribute
            return ""
        # Set the attribute and return the value, this is the first call
        setattr(once, namespaced_attr, True)
        return val

env.filters["only_once"] = only_once
```

This is slightly better because the value itself is used as the attribute to store (its name-spaced hash), so using the filter is cleaner:

**Define the macro (you can use inputs):**

```
{% macro custom_macro(input) %}
//
// {{ input }}
//
{% endmacro %}
```

**Use it:**

```
{{ custom_macro("foo") | only_once }}
{{ custom_macro("foo") | only_once }}
```